# Get data within an <a> within span tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I stuck in getting all data within span tag. My code gives me only every first value in every a() within the span tag and ignore other values. In my example: **(NB I reduced the span contents here, but it lot of  inside)**

> ```
> <span class="block-niveaux-sponsors">
> <a href="http://www.keolis.com/" id="a47-logo-part-keolis" target="_blank">
> <img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_keolis.201910210940.jpg"/>
> </a>
> <div class="clearfix"></div>
> </span>
>
> <span class="block-niveaux-sponsors">
> <a href="http://www.cg47.fr/" id="a47-logo-part-cg47" target="_blank">
> <img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_cg47.201910210940.jpg"/>
> </a>
> <div class="clearfix"></div>
> </span>
>
> <span class="block-niveaux-sponsors">
> <a href="http://www.errea.it/fr/" id="a47-logo-part-errea" target="_blank">
> <img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_errea.201910210940.jpg"/>
> </a>
> <div class="clearfix"></div>
> </span>
> ```

My code is:

```
page = urlopen(lien_suagen)
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
title_box_agen = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'autres'})
for tag in title_box_agen:
    for each_row in tag.find_all('span'):
        links = each_row.find('a', href=True)
        title = links.get('id')
        print(title)
```

This give me only the first **id** values in .
I want all id.

Comment: Change `links = each_row.find('a', href=True)` to `links = each_row.find_all('a', href=True)`

Comment: I did  thats first but it did not work. It generate an error in the last line `links.get()`

```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: Afterwards, you need to threat the `links` as an iterable (the `for link in links` loop and do the `link.get('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
page = urlopen(lien_suagen)
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
title_box_agen = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'autres'})
for tag in title_box_agen:
    for each_row in tag.find_all('span'):
        links = each_row.find_all('a', href=True)
        for link in links:
            title = link.get('id')
            print(title)
```

Comment: Super, this found all rows but `print(link.id)`  output `None` times numbers of  href. 
[lien_suagen](https://agen-rugby.com/fr/accueil) where i capture.

Comment: What is a sample of the output if you do `print(link)` ?

Comment: ```<a href="http://www.bmsfrance.fr/nous-connaitre/la-societe-UPSA/Pages/Home.aspx" id="a47-logo-part-upsa" target="_blank">
<img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_upsa.201910210940.jpg"/>
</a>
<a href="http://sbsr.fr/fr" id="a47-logo-part-sbsr" target="_blank">
<img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_sbsr.201910210940.jpg"/>
</a>
<a href="https://www.gifi.fr/" id="a47-logo-part-gifi" target="_blank">
<img src="images/visuels_footer/footer/part_gifi.201910210940.jpg"/>
</a>```
.....

Comment: it's all the <a>

Comment: So if you put `title = link.get('id')` and `print(title)`; is it working ?

Comment: It generates the error  i said you above.
[UPDATE]: It's ok, just I made put link**s** not link.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my previous comment with `link` instead of `links` (I also edited the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the link ids for each of the niveux class like this.
(not tested)

```
page = urlopen(lien_suagen)
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
spans_niveux = soup.find_all('span' class_='block-niveaux-sponsors')
for span in spans_niveux:
    link = span.find('a', href=True)
    id = link.id
    print(id)
```

Comment: what's class_ ??

Comment: since "class" is a reserved keyword in python, to get the "class" of the span (in this case it's "block-niveaux-sponsors") you have to use "class_" so python doesn't fail on it.